# My saved .py files can be seen in Pycharm but not in File Explorer

Tags: windows, python, desktop-computer, python3, pycharm

I already saved one file before. But when I do it now, it doesn't show in file explorer but shows in Pycharm "open" section. Any explanation and a way to fix this would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm and Windows Explorer]

Comment: Have you tried to press `F5` in the Explorer window? File changes are not always automatically updated in Windows Explorer.

Comment: yeah tried refreshing it. tried re-installing pycharm etc.

Comment: Execute `Reload from Disk` in Pycharm on the directory. And then in the context menu of the file in Pycharm `Open in`-> `Explorer`.

Comment: I did Reload from Disk then Opening the file from Pycharm > Explorer and it works but the problem remains when Opening Explorer first. I don't want to open pycharm always just to see my .py files. 

Also tried fragmenting all the disk where windows is and where I am saving the files. same issue

Comment: I would suggest that if the file doesn't show in the explorer after refreshing, it isn't there.  Also, the explorer DOES automatically refresh unless a shell extension has somehow hosed the directory change watcher API call that explorer uses.  Have you looked at this folder using the command line when it is under this state?  Does the file exist from the command line but not the windows explorer?